# Custom collation for postgres adapter on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, pg

On Postgres Collate and Ctype options are supported when creating database.

I need to set ones when rails is creating database, but it seems there's no option for this in database.yml in Rails 3

(but there is in edge Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6895)

How can i workaround this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Start by reading through the [official docs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ledger-smb/files/Beta%20Releases/1.3.31-rc1/)

Simply put, you can set environment variables to affect most of the initdb settings.  If you cannot set the arg for `--lc-collate`, you can set an environment variable of `LC_COLLATE`, and for `--lc_ctype` you set `LC_CTYPE` as an environment variable, etc.

If the environment variable is available, it will be used.

Comment: That documentation link is not pointing to anything PostgreSQL or Rails 3 related.